# Prevent word from being broken in TextView

Tags: android, textview

How do I prevent a word in a `TextView`from breaking in half when it doesn't fit on the current line and instead move to the next line.

```
|android goo|
|gle kitkat |
```

should instead be

```
|android    |
|google     |
|kitkat     |
```

The `TextView` is currently added to a `RelativeLayout` using this code:

```
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);

float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
int dpAsPixels = (int) (16*scale + 0.5f);
tv.setPadding(dpAsPixels, 0, dpAsPixels, 0);

tv.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

String fullString = "<b>" + user + ":</b> " + text;
fullString = fullString.replaceAll("\n", "<br />");
fullString = fullString.replaceAll(" ", "&#160");
tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(fullString));
tv.setTextSize(32f);
tv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.text));

layout.addView(tv);
```

Comment: the example you gave would actually move to the next line.Its only in the case of huge words ,like 15 characters odd(or  other languages) that Ihave faced the issue you are facing. 
Or do you face this issue in the example you have given too?

Comment: Check out : https://github.com/grantland/android-autofittextview

Comment: Did you try `android:minLines`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the problem is in following line

> fullString = fullString.replaceAll(" ", "&#160");

remove it and it will work as you need, you don't need to replace space with html code, `fromHtml` will do it for you

Comment: How do you put space between the text. For example to place "A*******B" in TextView using Html.fromHtml(). (Please assume star as a space) When I tried, the TextView is displaying "A B" (single space).

Comment: try `textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("A&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;B"));`

Comment: No luck. Same result.

Comment: can you copy paste your code or open new question ? I tested example above and it worked

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is this line:

```
fullString = fullString.replaceAll(" ", "&#160");
```

By doing this, you replace all "normal" spaces with non-breakable spaces (`&nbsp`). Since these spaces are *non-breakable*, they prevent a line break.

**Just remove this line** and the words won't break in half anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
android:scrollHorizontally="false"
```

to your TextView entry in your XML or call

```
setHorizontallyScrolling(false);
```

Docs [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setHorizontallyScrolling(boolean)).

Answer (score 0):

We can use Webview in some cases and justify the text help of html/css and then set the Text.